# Regex for matching all words before a specific character

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract all the words in a string before a specific character, in this example a colon (:).

For example:

```
String temp = "root/naming-will-look-like-this:1.0.0-SNAP";
```

From the string above I would like to return:

> "root" "naming" "will" "look" "like" "this"

I'm not great at regular expressions, and I've come up with this so far.

```
\w+(?=:)
```

Which only returns me the one word directly preceding the colon ("this").

How can I retrieve all words before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give us your definition of "word". Anything containing only A to Z, case insensitive?

Comment: yes, anything a-z, case insensitive. I would prefer if they were extracted as a "word and not individual characters. i.e. "root" instead of "r","o","o","t".

Comment: Since a single match operation can’t provide you multiple results, you have to be more specific about how you intend to collect the results. I.e., you can use `split` to create an array (then you need the delimiter pattern) or repeatedly call `find()` on a `Matcher` (then you need the word pattern)… If you want an array, you can do it in a single op like `String[] array = temp.split("\\W*:.*|\\W+");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a lookahead like this:

```
\w+(?=.*:)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HBka56/4)

`\w+` will match all words and the lookahead `(?=.*:)` asserts that we have a `:` ahead.

Comment: Note that this will find words up to the last colon, if there are multiple colons.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    String s = "root/naming-will-look-like-this:1.0.0-SNAP";
    s = s.replaceAll(":.*", "");
    String[] arr = s.split("\\W+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `\G` anchor in addition to Java's character class intersection you are able to store words into first capturing group:

```
\G(\w+)[\W&&[^:]]*
```

This won't bypass multiple colons like inside below input string:

```
root/naming-will-look-like-this:1.0.0-SNAP:some-thing-else
```